# Facebook need to relogin when user delete our app in Facebook app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Now i have to implement code for share status on user wall.
In the first time. User have been accept pemission of my app by click on "Turn on fb" button. However, they delete my app in them Facebook app after that. The next, they click on "Turn off fb" button and click on "Turn on fb" button again.
-> Actual: This button turned on without any request permission dialog.
-> Expect: This button must be off and request permission dialog must be show.

```
public void loginFragment(final ILoginFacebook loginFacebook) {
    Session.openActiveSession(mContext, mFragment, true,
        new StatusCallback() {
            //to only confirm permission one time
            private boolean isRequestPublishPermission = false;
            @Override
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                    Exception exception) {
                if (state.isOpened()) {
                    if (!isSubsetOf(mFacebookPermission.getPermissions(),
                            session.getPermissions())) {
                        if (!isRequestPublishPermission) {
                            session.requestNewPublishPermissions(new NewPermissionsRequest(
                                mFragment,
                                mFacebookPermission.getPermissions()));
                            isRequestPublishPermission = true;
                        } else {
                            loginFacebook.onLoginFBFailure();
                        }
                    } else {
                        loginFacebook.onLoginFBSuccess();
                    }
                } else {
                    int numCurrentPer = session.getPermissions().size();
                    int numOldPer = Session.getActiveSession().getPermissions().size();
                    if(numCurrentPer < numOldPer){
                        session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
                        isRequestPublishPermission = false;
                    }
                    loginFacebook.onLoginFBFailure();
                }
            }
        });
}
```

I set some Log to check data call back. At the last request. The session, stage alway {iOpened() == true} and list permission alway full.

Comment: The session (along with access token and permissions) are cached locally on the device, so until you try to make a request, it will not be updated. Normally, you can make a request to "/me" or "/me/permissions" just after opening the session, and if the user has deleted your app from Facebook, it will return an error and close the session.

Comment: So sorry but when i google "/me/permissions" or "/me", it show me no result... Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, the session is cached locally on the device after the user initially grants your app permissions. Afterwards, unless you explicitly call session.closeAndClearTokenInformation, it will use the cached information.

The implication of this is that you won't know if the token is still valid until you make a request to Facebook (this can come from the user deleting your app from FB, or changing their FB password, or other similar scenarios).

There are a couple of ways to handle this. One is to just carry on with your application as usual, and when you make a request to the Graph API, handle the errors that come back (see the Handling Errors section of [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#errors)).

The other is to make a request to Facebook right after you open a session, this could be a "/me" request:

```
Request meRequest = Request.newMeRequest(session, callback);
meRequest.executeAsync();
```

If the user has deleted your app, then this request will error out, and you should use the error handling tactics I linked to above to handle it.